# Rigidity of Borel Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology

Let $\mathfrak b$ be a Borel subalgebra of dimension $n$ in a real semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. I am trying to reconcile two facts about $\mathfrak b$:

1. $\mathfrak b$ is rigid, that is, the orbit of its law is open (even, Zariski-open) in the variety $\mathcal R_n$ of solvable Lie algebras of dimension $n$. This can be proven as follows:  $H^2(\mathfrak b, \mathfrak b)=0$ (where $\mathfrak b$ acts in $\mathfrak b$ via the adjoint representation), see e.g. [Leger and Luks, [Cohomology theorems for Borel-like solvable Lie algebras in arbitrary characteristic](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/cohomology-theorems-for-borellike-solvable-lie-algebras-in-arbitrary-characteristic/FD5CED0DFC27241DA234ACBF5785C764),
   *Canadian J. Math.* **24** (1972), 1019-1026, Corollary 5.6]. And then this vanishing is sufficient (though not necessary) to ensure that $\mathfrak b$ is rigid, see e.g. [Carles, [On the structure of rigid Lie algebras](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=AIF_1984__34_3_65_0), *Ann. Inst. Fourier* (Grenoble) **34** (1984), no. 3, 65-82.]
2. There seemingly exist solvable Lie algebras that can degenerate to $\mathfrak b$. Here is a minimal example where $\mathfrak g$ is rank one and $n=3$: consider $\mathfrak s = \mathfrak t + \mathfrak a$, where $\mathfrak a =\operatorname{span}(X,Y)$ is a $2$-dimensional abelian ideal and $\mathfrak t$ is a $1$-dimensional torus of derivations of $\mathfrak a$ generated by $T$ with
   $$ \operatorname{ad} T_{\mid \mathfrak a} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0  & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
   that is $[T,X] = X$ and $[T,Y] = X+Y$. Now, for $t \in (0, + \infty)$ let $\varphi(t) \in \operatorname{GL(\mathfrak s)}$ be diagonal and such that $\varphi_t(X) = X, \varphi_t(Y) = e^{-t}Y, \varphi_t(T) = T$. Then $\mathfrak s$ degenerates through $(\varphi_t)$ to the Borel subalgebra of $\mathfrak o (3,1)$ when $t \to + \infty$. (And $\mathfrak t + \mathfrak a$ becomes the Cartan decomposition of $\mathfrak b$ in the limit.)

So where is the snag?

Comment: By "Borel subalgebra" you mean the same as "minimal parabolic"? (I remember hearing subtle differences in the non-split case but I'm not sure)

Comment: @Ycor for me Borel subalgebra means maximal solvable subalgebra, and parabolic means contains a Borel subalgebra. So yes, for me those would be the same, but I would be glad to understand if there is a better/more correct definition where they differ...

Comment: Oh, I see one issue related to your point. Those are real algebras, not complex ones. The limit algebra  in 2. is maximal among the subalgebras of $\mathfrak{o}(3,1)$ isomorphic to algebras of upper triangular real matrices, however it is not maximal solvable subalgebra. So it may be that it has $H^2(\mathfrak b, \mathfrak b)$ nonzero.

Comment: OK, YCor's comment got me back on track. I've checked that because I assumed $\mathfrak g$ **real**, $\mathfrak b$ in 2. is not a Borel subalgebra, neither is it Borel-like as in Leger and Luks' terminology from the paper cited above, so their vanishing theorem does not hold for $\mathfrak b$. I also computed by hand part of $H^2(\mathfrak b, \mathfrak b)$ on the $3$-dimensional example, the degeneration I pointed comes from a $2$-cocycle which is not a coboundary. I do not post this as an answer yet because someone may have a more general/insightful view on this.

Answer (score 2):

So here's the fix thanks to YCor's comment, in the case I managed to confuse anyone.

Let $\mathfrak g$ be the split real form of a semisimple complex Lie algebra.
There is a difference between:

- Borel subalgebras of $\mathfrak g$, that is maximal solvable subalgebras of $\mathfrak g$.
- Maximal *split-solvable* subalgebras of $\mathfrak g$; I am not aware of a good terminology for them. They are real forms of Borel subalgebras in $\mathfrak g\otimes \mathbf C$.

$H^2(\mathfrak b_0, \mathfrak b_0)=0$ holds for every Borel subalgebra $\mathfrak b_0$ of $\mathfrak g$, but fails for the maximal split-solvable algebra $\mathfrak b$ in the question (and I now suspect, many of them).

Use the notation from the question, denote $(\xi, \eta, \theta)$ the dual basis to $(X,Y,T)$. Then by some computations (I skip the details)

$$ \begin{array}
& d(\xi\otimes X) = 0  & d(\xi \otimes Y) = 0  & d(\xi \otimes T) = \xi \wedge \eta \otimes Y + \xi \wedge \theta \otimes T   \\
  d(\eta \otimes X) = 0 & d(\eta \otimes Y) = 0 & d(\eta \otimes T) = - \xi \wedge \eta \otimes X + \eta \wedge \theta \otimes T \\
d(\theta \otimes X)=0  & d(\theta \otimes Y) = 0  & d (\theta \otimes T)=- \eta \wedge \theta \otimes Y - \xi \wedge \theta \otimes X.
\end{array} 
$$

Hence $B^2(\mathfrak b, \mathfrak b) = \left\{ \xi \wedge \eta \otimes (aY - bX)  + \xi \wedge \theta \otimes (aT - cX) + \eta \wedge \theta \otimes (bT - cY) \right\}_{a,b,c \in \mathbf R}$.

Set $\gamma = \theta \wedge \eta \otimes X$, so that along the degeneration $\mathfrak s \to \mathfrak b$, $\mu_{\mathfrak s} = \mu_{\mathfrak b} + e^{-t} \gamma$ if we put $\mu_{\mathfrak b}$, $\mu_{\mathfrak s}$ the laws of $\mathfrak b$ and $\mathfrak s$ respectively on a common vector space. Note that
\begin{align}
d\gamma ( X \wedge Y \wedge T) & = [X, (\theta \wedge \eta \otimes X)(Y \wedge T)] 
- [Y, (\theta \wedge \eta) \otimes X (X \wedge T)] \\
& \quad + [T, (\theta \wedge \eta \otimes X) (X \wedge Y) ]
- \gamma ([X,Y], T)  + \gamma ([X,T], Y) - \gamma([Y,T], X) \\
&  = 0
\end{align}
hence $[\gamma]$ defines a nonzero cohomology class.
The same computation should provide the full $H^2(\mathfrak b, \mathfrak b)$, and possibly with extra effort $H^2(\mathfrak b, \mathfrak b)$ when $\mathfrak b$ is maximal split solvable in $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak o (n,1)$, $n>2$; it is known that only finitely many isomorphism classes of Lie algebra can degenerate to such a $\mathfrak b$. [Lauret,
[Degenerations of Lie algebras and geometry of Lie groups](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0926224502001468?via%3Dihub).
*Differential Geom. Appl.* **18** (2003), no. 2, 177-194].